# Div manipulation with jquery / each

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, each

Well what I'm trying to do is, I run an ajax, where I get the result of my select and I get them in response. What I need to do is to foreach the results I receive, and with jquery add this data to my div.

My div and my ajax:

```js
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '',
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false
  })
  .done(function(response) {
      response = JSON.parse(response);

      if (response.length != 0) {

        $(".pesquisa").each(response, function(index, value) {
          //AQUI É ONDE EU DEVERIA PEGAR OS DADOS E FAZER UM LOOP NA DIV
        });
      });
```

```html
<div class="pesquisa">
  <div class="">
    <div class="">
      <span class="name">NAME HERE</span>
      <span class="descricao">
                                 DESCRIPTION HERE
                                </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="endereco">
      <p><strong>ADDRESS HERE</strong></p>
    </div>
    <div id="accordion">
      <div class="card-warning">
        <div class="card-header">
          <h4 class="card-title w-100">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#avisos" class="d-block w-100">
                                                ALERT HERE
                                            </a>
          </h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-footer text-right">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary">1</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I already did something similar but inside each I just added a field like this:

```
$('#ID').append($('<option>').text(value.Nome).attr('value', value.ID));
```

Where I looped and placed the results of a tag and brought all the results I received from the response, I tried to do the same for my div, but I don't know exactly how to make my forech results appear in my div.

Comment: Your snippet generates a syntax error. I suggest eliminating all syntax errors first. Also, why do you say you "can't execute the loop"?  Are you sure it's not executing? Are you getting errors in your web console?

Comment: Assuming the ajax works, just post a [mcve] with the object you receive and the code to manipulate it

Comment: You likely want to do [`$.each(response,function(index, value) {`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

Comment: correcting my question, the loop works brings the objects, but how do I show these results by looping the div this is the part I'm not able to execute

Comment: Why don't you include the ajax response data in your question??  Are you sure your ajax response parses out to an array?

Comment: POST the OBJECT here! Please?!